# Javascript: replace string function not working in IE7-8

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer, str-replace

I've created a JSFiddle that shows my program:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Fx3a/10/

As you'll see when a user types in the input field and clicks 'go' the program will try to find that value in the list of links and highlight the word in yellow (by adding a span element around the word and giving it a class of 'highlight').

If a user checks for another word the existing spans are all removed and new ones are put in place.

It is this removeSpan function that is not working IE7-8. It will successfully highlight the relevant words but it won't remove the existing spans if the user enters another value.

Does anyone know what the problem might be here?

Comment: Is jsfiddle down (or really slow) right now for anyone?

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome either.  When you search for one term, then for a second, only the first match of the first term is removed, not all of them.

Comment: I just fired up WinXP/IE7 VM and run your jsFiddle - object doesn't support this property or method.  Line 245, Char 9

Comment: @KrisKrause I get that error too although it says 'line 193, char 5' for me. It's strange because my script doesn't go to 193 lines. In addition, IE7 doesn't give me any errors on my localhost when I run this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points:

Changing your regExp from `/^\s+/` to `/^\s+|\s+$/g` might be useful as it will trim trailing whitespace, too.

Change `if (text_input === "") {` to `if (removeSpaces === "") {` otherwise you get horrible results if you just enter a space.

Why are you declaring the functions `highlight`, `removeSpan` and `addSpan` when you only call them in one place?  Just put their code where you call them (unless, of course, you want to use them elsewhere, too).

Why are you creating the temporary vars `newstr` and `newstr2`?  Just reassign the result of the `anchor_text.replace()` call back into `anchor_text`.

Pass regexes in the replace function instead of strings.

Implementing all of these changes, we get:

```
document.getElementById('check-list').onclick = function() {

    text_input = document.search.search_list.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");

    if (text_input.length) {

        var anchor = document.getElementById('results').getElementsByTagName('a');
        var alength = anchor.length;

        for (var x = 0; x < alength; x++) {
            var anchor_text = anchor[x].innerHTML;

            anchor_text = anchor_text
                .replace(/<span class="highlight">/gi, "")
                    .replace(/<\/span>/gi, "");

            anchor[x].innerHTML = anchor_text;

            var re = new RegExp(text_input, "gi");

            if (anchor_text.search(re) !== -1) {
                anchor_text = anchor_text.replace(re, "<span class='highlight'>$&</span>");
                anchor[x].innerHTML = anchor_text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for those tips on improving the quality of my JS code. I've updated the example on JS Fiddle with those improvements: http://jsfiddle.net/8Fx3a/10/. However, I'm still having the same problem in IE. Also what version of Chrome are you running? I've tested this on Chrome 14 for Mac and Chrome 12-14 on Windows and the program works fine for me.

Comment: I'm on a different machine now; not sure what version I was using earlier, but it worked after my modifications, but not before, for some reason.  IE 9 worked fine for me.  I'll check IE 7 when I'm back on a Windows machine later.  FYI, this works fine on Chromium 14.0.835.186 (Linux).

Comment: Right, sorry for the delay, I've only just got access to IE again.  The problem is that IE 7 is not returning the exact same innerHTML as you put there earlier on. Instead of `<span class="highlight">`, it is using `<SPAN class=highlight>` (note missing quotes).  Changing the `.replace(/<span class="highlight">/gi, "")` call to `.replace(/<span class="?highlight"?>/gi, "")` gets around this.  See [the update here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Fx3a/17/).

Comment: Great thanks very much for that. What do the question marks do there? Are they escaping? Also what tool did you use to find out that was what IE7 was outputting?

Comment: The question mark in this context in a regex means whatever comes before is optional; it can be there either zero or one times and the regex will match (compare with `*` for zero or more, and `+` for one or more).  I used IE9, hit F12 to view the developer console, changed the browser mode here to IE7 and added `console.log(anchor_text);` after the two `.replace` calls.  For console-less browsers, `alert(anchor_text);` would have worked instead.